# Cannot upgrade to windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1

I've run into some trouble installing windows 10. I have windows 8.1 and use an SSD as my main drive.

"We couldn't update the system reserved partition"
The trouble seems to come from the recovery drive being full.

I've found this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3086249

I have a GPT partition.

I followed it up until the point it wants me to go into the recovery drive and delete unnecessary files. I restarted explorer.exe as admin, tried to open file explorer. But it takes about 5 minutes for it to open and when it does, I cannot access the recovery drive, I don't have permissions.

I tried googling but I can't find a way to fix the recovery partition drive.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, sorry to answer my own question.

I solved this by, using Explorer++ in Administrator mode and deleting unused language folders (backed up just in case). For some reason File Explorer couldn't handle it.

Comment: [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). But maybe you could specify which files you deleted with more detail.

Comment: Well the windows help page didn't really specify. I assumed language folders that were not en-US... I'll tell you if anything goes wrong. For example: hu-HU, hr-HR, en-GB, bg-BG etc. etc.

Comment: Windows 10 installed! Had another unrelated error. Using Explorer++ did the trick in the case tho.